# Get month from date string?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I know that I can get the month from a date object using:

```
var d = new Date();
var n = d.getMonth();
```

But in my code I have a `$scope.start` property that seems to not be a date object. It is:

```
2016-02-17T14:39:00Z
```

How can I extract the month from `$scope.start`?

Comment: have you tried using the data filter? https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/date

Comment: Check for the Date constructors here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This will give you a month as a number from 0 to 11

```
 var date = new Date('2016-12-17T14:39:00Z');
 var month = date.getMonth();
```

Comment: Simpler and more efficient: `var month = '2016-12-17T14:39:00Z'.split('-')[1]`.

Comment: You mean someone will know how the Date constructor parses strings, what *getMonth* does and that dates are zero indexed, but doesn't know how *split* works? Even with a variable called *month*? Not all browsers in use will correctly parse the string either.

Comment: If you see a line like "var month = $scope.start.split('-')[1];", you have to figure out what is being parsed, but when using a Date(), it's pretty obvious you're creating a date object and extracting the month from it.

Maybe it's just preference, but I like to be a little more verbose in these kinds of situations.

Answer (score 2):

```
$scope.start = new Date('2016-02-17T14:39:00Z');
$scope.startMonth= $scope.start.getMonth() + 1;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ms403Ly8/57/

Answer (score 1):

May be this will help you pass the date string to Date() constructor.

now the date object is of date contain in string and if u print month or alert it will give u month-1 value.

here is code. please have a look on it

```js
var d = new Date('2016-02-17T14:39:00Z');
var n = d.getMonth();


alert(n);

var d = new Date('2016-03-17T14:39:00Z');
var n = d.getMonth();


alert(n)
```

Answer (score 1):

May I recommend the following approach

```
var n = new Date($scope.start);
var month = n.getMonth();
```

You need to convert the string to a date object.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to do it by using split ! 
Try something like this

```
$scope.start = "2016-02-17T14:39:00Z";
{{start.split('-')[0]}}

now you will get, "Month" while you try "{{start.split('-')[1]}}"
```

Comment: This is far too simple and sensible to be accepted.

Comment: Just be aware that it will return a string and not an integer, which can be tricky if you want to do calculations.

Comment: I think it is very useful/simple to do this when we just need to display month !

Answer (score 0):

But Normally 0 means jan, 1 -> feb, 2-> mar,... 
so only we did some +1, -1...

```html
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<title>Get Previous next Day, Month, Year Month Time in Angularjs</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.9/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var app = angular.module('sampleapp', [])
app.controller('samplecontrol', function ($scope) {
 
var previousMonth = new Date()
$scope.pmonth = previousMonth.getMonth();
var currentMonth = new Date()
$scope.cmonth = currentMonth.getMonth() + 1;
var nextMonth = new Date()
$scope.nmonth = nextMonth.getMonth() + 2;
 
});
</script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="sampleapp" data-ng-controller="samplecontrol">
<form id="form1">
<div>
 
Previous Month:<b> {{pmonth }}</b><br />
Current Month:<b> {{cmonth }}</b><br /> 
Next Month:<b> {{nmonth }}</b><br /> 
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```